# Why would switching from AspectJ to Proxy mode cause a "TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query" to no longer occur?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-aspects

I have an issue with my use of Spring Data Jpa & Hibernate.

Here is the exception I get:

```
2017-05-21 21:42:20.761 DEBUG 11765 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : committing
2017-05-21 21:42:20.765  INFO 11765 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener : Session Metrics {
    14574 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    55978 nanoseconds spent preparing 2 JDBC statements;
    2315850 nanoseconds spent executing 2 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
2017-05-21 21:42:20.779 ERROR 11765 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query] with root cause

javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
```

When I change my transaction management from AspectJ-mode

```
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
```

To the default Proxy-mode:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
```

The exception does not occur any longer.

Here are the methods in calling order:

From `MessageRestController`:

```
@RestController
...
@PatchMapping("mark-messages-as-read/{otherId}")
public void markMessagesAsRead(@CurrentUserAccount UserAccount me, @PathVariable Long otherId) {
    UserAccount other = userAccountService.findUserAccountById(otherId);
    messageService.markMessagesAsRead(me, other);
}
```

From `MessageService`:

```
@Service
@Transactional
...
@Override
public void markMessagesAsRead(UserAccount me, UserAccount other) {
    Assert.notNull(me);
    Assert.notNull(other);
    messageRepository.markMessagesAsRead(me, other);
}
```

From `MessageRepository`:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update Message m set m.messageRead = true where m.recipient = :me and m.sender= :other")
void markMessagesAsRead(@Param("me") UserAccount me, @Param("other") UserAccount other);
```

I am extremely curious to know why switching from **AspectJ-mode to Proxy-mode causes the exception no longer to occur**.

Can someone please advise?

**edit**: Here is the service implementation declaration:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MessageServiceImpl implements MessageService {
```

and from the service interface:

```
void markMessagesAsRead(UserAccount me, UserAccount other);
```

Comment: Can you show the declaration for the service class (does it implement any interface, for instance)? If a service interface is involved (which most likely seems to be the case due to the `@Override` on the `markMessagesAsRead` method), can you also show the full declaration of the `markMessagesAsRead` in the interface?

Comment: Using `mode=ASPECTJ` will only work if you combine it with loadtime or compile timeweaving. If you don't use that `mode=ASPECTJ` will not do anything as aspects will not be applied.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Thanks for you comment. I see. Transactions in the rest of my app do work OK though...

Comment: @balteo, is `MessageService` marked as `@Transactional` as well?

Comment: Is it or do you think they are working... For reading you don't really need an explicit transaction, only modifications. If you are also using `HibernateTemplate` or `JpaTemplate` it also changes a little (as it will do an on demand transaction then, loosing the ability to rollback multiple actions in a single transaction as you will have multiple transactions). So I guess you think they are working because you don't see errors but in reality they don't.

Comment: @manish Yes the implementation is indeed marked as transactional

Comment: @M.Deinum What you say is interesting... Can you please give me a surefire way to know whether or not aspectJ is activated and working on an application (log, debug)?

Comment: @M.Deinum I am just wondering how my other services can persist data if aspectJ is not working. Can you please kindly provide links or information about the mentions of JpaTemplate?

Comment: I have opened another post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44115996/ regarding determining whether aspectj mode is on of off.

Comment: As stated mode aspect will only work if you use load or compile time weaving. If you don't use that it won't work, the fact that it appears to work might be due to use of other technologies but then it worked more out of luck then by design.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the official [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction-declarative-aspectj) for AspectJ usage?

You have to use AspectJ for this to weave your application code.

Of course with the default setting it's working well as Spring AOP is creating runtime proxies for your classes.

Comment: Hi. I forgot to mention that the rest of my app works fine with aspect j. Only the above method call has an issue...

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "with the default setting"? Do you  mean without the **AdviceMode.ASPECTJ**?