# Surefire way of checking whether aspectJ mode is working for spring transaction management

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

I am working on a spring boot application. I have tried to enable **AspectJ mode** for **transaction management** as follows:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
```

I am suspecting the aspectJ mode is not working and I would like to know whether or not AspectJ mode is indeed enabled for my application.

Can someone please provide a way to check that (e.g. through enabling a logger or debugging)?

Comment: As stated in the other question `mode=ASPECTJ` will only work if you use load or compile time weaving. If you don't use those it won't work. If you have to ask what load- and/or compile time weaving are that is a pretty good indicator that it isn't something you use. (as either are a bit of a pain to setup).

Comment: Look for the class `AbstractTransactionAspect` and put a breakpoint in the `around` method (this method may be called something else if you use an IDE and the IDE loaded the class from the compiled binary code). If the AspectJ transaction advice is being applied, the code will hit the breakpoint for every method/class annotated with `@Transactional`.