# @Transactional throws TransactionRequiredException with ASPECTJ even with compile-time weaving plugin?

Tags: spring-boot, transactions, aspectj, spring-transactions

`@Transactional` throws `TransactionRequiredException`: No `EntityManager` with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process persist
when using AspectJ even with compile-time weaving plugin and all AspectJ dependencies and Development tools installed.

Possibly similar question: [Why would switching from AspectJ to Proxy mode cause a "TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query" to no longer occur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44101198/why-would-switching-from-aspectj-to-proxy-mode-cause-a-transactionrequiredexcep)

I intend to use AspectJ instead of Spring AOP to increase the performance of my app.

Here I presented part of three files. AspectJ Development Toolkit is installed.

pom.xml:

```xml
...

      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dev.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.1</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>


...


            <build>
                <plugins>                  
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>compile</goal>
                                    <!-- <goal>test-compile</goal> -->
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <complianceLevel>17</complianceLevel>
                            <forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile>
                            <weaveDirectories>
                                <weaveDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</weaveDirectory>
                            </weaveDirectories>
                            <aspectLibraries>
                                <aspectLibrary>
                                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                                </aspectLibrary>
                            </aspectLibraries>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

XService.java:

```java
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class BridgeService {
...
    @Transactional
    private void persistAvatarResource(String resCode, String start) {
        AvatarRes avatarRes = new AvatarRes();
        avatarRes.setClient(client);
        avatarRes.setAvatar(avatar);
        avatarRes.setRes(getResource(resCode));
        avatarRes.setStart(PHPHelper.toInt(start));

        entityManager.persist(avatarRes);

    }
...
}
```

DatabaseConfig.java:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.lixar.apba.repository")
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "springSecurityAuditorAware")
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseConfiguration.class);

    @Inject
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private MetricRegistry metricRegistry;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    @ConditionalOnExpression("!environment.acceptsProfiles('cloud') && !environment.acceptsProfiles('heroku')")
    public DataSource dataSource(DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties, JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties, CacheManager cacheManager) {
        log.debug("Configuring Datasource");
        if (dataSourceProperties.getUrl() == null) {
            log.error("Your database connection pool configuration is incorrect! The application" +
                    " cannot start. Please check your Spring profile, current profiles are: {}",
                Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));

            throw new ApplicationContextException("Database connection pool is not configured correctly");
        }
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDataSourceClassName(dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName());
        config.addDataSourceProperty("url", dataSourceProperties.getUrl());
        if (dataSourceProperties.getUsername() != null) {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("user", dataSourceProperties.getUsername());
        } else {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("user", ""); // HikariCP doesn't allow null user
        }
        if (dataSourceProperties.getPassword() != null) {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("password", dataSourceProperties.getPassword());
        } else {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("password", ""); // HikariCP doesn't allow null password
        }
        
        config.setConnectionTimeout(jHipsterProperties.getDatasource().getConnectionTimeout());
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(jHipsterProperties.getDatasource().getMaximumPoolSize());

        //MySQL optimizations, see https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MySQL-Configuration
        if ("com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource".equals(dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName())) {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", jHipsterProperties.getDatasource().isCachePrepStmts());
            config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", jHipsterProperties.getDatasource().getPrepStmtCacheSize());
            config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", jHipsterProperties.getDatasource().getPrepStmtCacheSqlLimit());
        }
        if (metricRegistry != null) {
            config.setMetricRegistry(metricRegistry);
        }
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

   
    
    @Bean
    public Hibernate5Module hibernate5Module() {
        return new Hibernate5Module();
    }
}
```

Comment: Without having looked at your Java code yet, I see that you are trying to use a super old version of AspectJ Maven plugin from 2013, supporting Java 7. But then you try to compile with compliance level 17. That is expecting a bit too much. Does your project even compile without errors? Not even the current version 1.14.0 of that plugin supports Java 17 yet, which is why I am maintaining the [AspectJ.dev fork](https://github.com/dev-aspectj/aspectj-maven-plugin), which is much more up to date, has more features and, if configured correctly, supports Java 18 (or even higher).

Comment: Feedback, please. I cannot help you without feedback. Does it work after changing and upgrading AspectJ Maven? If not, where is your full, minimal, reproducible example? Ideally, it would be a small GitHub project which I can compile and run in order to analyse your problem.

Comment: It keeps throwing the same error. I am not sure where is the build.ajproperties file. The code is at https://github.com/Einwith/TransactionRequiredException

Comment: Ugh, this project has been downloading dependencies for over 10 minutes and still is not finished. I would much prefer an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) focused on reproducing the problem, not a big application which downloads the world.

Comment: BTW, did you even try to build your own project before posting it on GitHub? `basedir ...\src\main\java\com\lixar\apba does not exist`. Now I first have to try and fix your copy & paste directory mess-up.

Comment: I moved the sources into the newly created directory _src/main/java/com/lixar/apba_, but cannot compile the project because many classes in several packages are missing. Like this, I cannot help you. I need a minimal project which compiles, runs and reproduces your problem. This one does not even build.